# While we add addFilter before in our Security Filter bean . Bean is not creating and and produce error, mentioned filter is empty. Spring Boot Kotlin

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, jwt

Hello I implementing Spring Security. I Found error while I Application is run.
Not Creating Bean Produce Error.

Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/compilers/tripsntours/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Object.getClass()" because "filter" is null

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/compilers/tripsntours/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Object.getClass()" because "filter" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:769) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:127) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1397) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at com.compilers.tripsntours.TripsnToursApplication$Companion.main(TripsnToursApplication.kt:65) ~[main/:na]
    at com.compilers.tripsntours.TripsnToursApplication.main(TripsnToursApplication.kt) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/compilers/tripsntours/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Object.getClass()" because "filter" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:652) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1621) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1585) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1476) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1363) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:809) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Object.getClass()" because "filter" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Object.getClass()" because "filter" is null
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.addFilterAtOffsetOf(HttpSecurity.java:3056) ~[spring-security-config-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.addFilterBefore(HttpSecurity.java:3050) ~[spring-security-config-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at com.compilers.tripsntours.config.SecurityConfig.securityFilterChain(SecurityConfig.kt:62) ~[main/:na]
    at com.compilers.tripsntours.config.SecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$securityFilterChain$3(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at com.compilers.tripsntours.config.SecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:257) ~[spring-core-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at com.compilers.tripsntours.config.SecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.securityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

**SecurityConfig.kt**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
//@EnableJpaRepositories
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    val customUserDetailservice : CustomUserDetailservice  ?= null

    @Autowired
    val jwtAuthenticationFilter : JwtAuthenticationFilter ?= null

    @Autowired
    val jwtAuthenticationEntryRequestPoint: JwtAuthenticationEntryRequestPoint ?= null

    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity) : SecurityFilterChain {

        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests { requests ->
                requests
                    .requestMatchers("/api/user/login","/api/user/registerUser")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                   // .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(this.jwtAuthenticationEntryRequestPoint)

            }
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
        http.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider())
        val build : DefaultSecurityFilterChain = http.build()
        return build
    }
    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }
    @Bean
    fun daoAuthenticationProvider(): DaoAuthenticationProvider? {
        val provider = DaoAuthenticationProvider()
        provider.setUserDetailsService(this.customUserDetailservice)
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
        return provider
    }
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun authepnticationManagerBean(configuration: AuthenticationConfiguration): AuthenticationManager? {
       return configuration.authenticationManager
    }


}
```

**JwtAuthenticationFilter.kt**

```
@Component
class JwtAuthenticationFilter : OncePerRequestFilter() {

    @Autowired
    private val userDetailsService: UserDetailsService? = null

    @Autowired
    private val jwtTokenHelper: JwtTokenHelper? = null

    @Throws(ServletException::class, IOException::class)
    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {

//      1. get token
        val requestToken = request.getHeader("Authorization")
        val headerNames = request.headerNames
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            println(headerNames.nextElement())
        }
        // Bearer 2352523sdgsg
        println(requestToken)
        var username: String? = null
        var token: String? = null
        if (requestToken != null && requestToken.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            token = requestToken.substring(7)
            try {
                username = jwtTokenHelper!!.getUsernameFromToken(token)
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                println("Unable to get Jwt token")
            } catch (e: ExpiredJwtException) {
                println("Jwt token has expired")
            } catch (e: MalformedJwtException) {
                println("invalid jwt")
            }
        } else {
            println("Jwt token does not begin with Bearer")
        }

        // once we get the token , now validate
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication == null) {
            val userDetails = userDetailsService!!.loadUserByUsername(username)
            if (jwtTokenHelper!!.validateToken(token, userDetails)) {
                val usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.authorities
                )
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.details = WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
            } else {
                println("Invalid jwt token")
            }
        } else {
            println("username is null or context is not null")
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
}
```

**Main Class.kt**

```
@SpringBootApplication
class TripsnToursApplication : CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    val passwordEncode: PasswordEncoder? = null

    @Autowired
    private val roleRepo: RoleRepo? = null

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            runApplication<TripsnToursApplication>(*args)
        }
    }



    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun run(vararg args: String?) {
        try {
            val role1 = Role()
            role1.id = ADMIN_USER
            role1.name = "ROLE_ADMIN"
            val role2 = Role()
            role2.id = TOURIST_USER
            role2.name = "ROLE_TOURIST"
            val role3 = Role()
            role3.id = AGENCEY_USER
            role3.name = "ROLE_AGENCY"
            val roles: List<Role> = listOf(role1, role2, role3)
            val result: List<Role> = roleRepo!!.saveAll(roles)
            result.forEach(Consumer<Role> { r: Role -> System.out.println(r.name) })


        } catch (e: Exception) {

            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: it is just kotlin syntax

Comment: It is not about kotlin syntax it is the concept of autowiring. You should check all solutions. There are several problems why bean is not injected.